# How can I stop this window from sliding down?

Tags: windows

I have what I think is a single-hung window that keeps sliding down (when it's open).  I do not see any way to remove the sash (so that I can access the spring mechanism).  All instructions I see on the web claim that there is either a release mechanism on the top of the sash or take out clips on both sides of the window frame.  However, I see neither.  Additionally, I do not know my window manufacturer and cannot find any marking on the window.  Link to the pictures of my window is provided.

[image]
[image] [image] [image]
<sup>*Click for larger view*</sup>

Pictures:

1. Top of sash
2. Frame above sash
3. Frame below (open) sash
4. Bottom of (open) sash connecting to the frame

My questions are:

1. What kind of a window is this? (e.g. single-hung?)
2. How can I fix it to stop sliding down?  If I need to remove the sash first, how do I do it?

Comment: What's that copper thing in picture 4?  Also, this might not be what you're looking for but... Would sticking a piece of wood underneath the window when it's open not solve the problem?

Comment: If that springy wingy thing in pic 4 is doing what I think it's doing, roughening up the surface it's pressing against should help. Try putting a piece of duct tape in there for the spring to ride over. If that helps, try a rough coat of paint, or even a thin glued plastic strip to increase the force the spring thing exerts.

Answer (score 1):

A wooden dowel sawed off to the right length to prop the window open is the traditional answer. You can keep the dowel on the sill when you're not using it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a single hung window.  I don't know the brand.  It appears that to remove the sash that the channel (the channel that contains the copper colored spring in the last picture) must be retractable (probably spring loaded).  So I'd push the channel back into the slot it's in.  If I'm guessing correctly, when you apply pressure the channel will retract away from contact with the sash, which will leave the sash free to pivot away from the channel on which you're pushing.

However, it looks to me like the copper colored spring is intended, via friction, to keep the sash from gravity dropping.  If the inside of that channel has been oiled, that would explain a lot.  If you can get the sash out, then get the spring out, you may be able to bend the spring so that it increases its friction in the channel.  But the spring may just as well snap.  So it's dicey.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your local bike store and ask for carbon seatpost gel. A tube should be around $10/10€.

It contains friction enhancing components that should reduce sliding. Use just a tiny bit and on both sides at the same time.

[image: seatpost gel]